# Jar and File I/O

Tags: java, properties, jar, io

in my Java project i have some propertie files in a folder src/properties. When running the application in eclipse loading and saving the file with the following code is no problem:

```
    // create and load default properties
    Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    File file = new File("src/properties/defaultProperties");
    if (!file.exists()){
        // Create new properties file
            ...
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("defaultProperties");
        defaultProps.store(out, "---No Comment---");
        out.close();
    } else {
        // Load existing properties file
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        defaultProps.load(in);
        in.close();
    }
```

However when i creata a Runnable Jar file with eclipse the properties don't get loaded correctly. The same happens when saving the file. I read something about :

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

But in this case how can i check with an input stream if the file is existing? How is the right way to do this I/O such that it works in executable Jar files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather use [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html). It's similar to `java.util.Properties` with the difference that it's not stored in properties files, but in platform specific config management. On Windows machines for example, that's the registry.

#### See also:

- [Overview of Preferences API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

is the right way to go. Your properties file needs to be packaged within your jar file, and the path (as used above) should match the properties file path *within* the jar file.

Note that you wouldn't write into this. If you're packaging a jar then it's (to all intents and purposes) immutable.

Comment: but what do i write for !file.exists() then? How can i do this on an input stream?

Comment: You'll get an exception if it can't open it. Remember that it's *not* a file. If you can't find it, then it's likely (unless you've designed it to be like this) a programming or jar assembly problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs of ClassLoader

getResourceAsStream Returns

> An input stream for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to write resources back into Jar files.  The archives are usually locked by the JVM.

Instead serialize the new options to a place on the local file system (many options are available as to how to achieve this) and check for that changed file before defaulting to the internal properties.